# разрешения в манифесте для AdMob

Tags: android

для рекламы adMob в инструкции говорится, что нужно 2 стандартных разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

а стоит ли добавлять еще эти 2, увеличится ли доход??

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: В 5 раз (нет)...

Comment: в 3 раза тоже оч круто